# running TestNG in command line fail

Tags: testng

when I running TestNG in command line, throw exception：

> C:\TEST>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 6 more

Comment: Did you read that exception ? It' talking about `Parameters` and `Xml`and class definition

Answer (score 1):

jcommander seems missing.  You have to add it in your classpath too because it is a mandatory dependency when you run TestNG in command line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to download the TestNG library archive, then extract the contents into a folder. Some people might add this folder to their project and call it "lib", but in my case I called the folder "TestNG" and put it on the C:\ directory.

I have downloaded the 7.0.0 release. http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

This will work for you:

1. Open CLI , cd into your project folder location, and type this command:

   set classpath=C:\[your project folder in eclipse]\bin;C:\TestNG\plugins*

Note: there must be no spaces between the = equals sign.

2. Run the command:

   java -classpath %classpath% org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

or.. you can type out the long command:

```
java -classpath C:\eclipse-2018\Tests\bin;C:\TestNG\plugins\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

If you're still getting a problem, you must refactor your class files to a new name, so that new .class files will be generated in the \bin folder. Then update the testng.xml script with the new class names.